"unlimited" in store names and "limited" in vehicle models
I see a lot of stores with the word unlimited at the end of the name. "Things Unlimited" (thrift store), "Taste Unlimited", "Eyewear Unlimited". Is this meant as a hyperbole for the amount of selection (or for the amount of quality)?
I see vehicles with print on the outside next to the model name that says limited? Is that to mean, they bought a vehicle without the bells and whistles? Why would someone want that fact on display?

I think it just clicked, for the vehicles, it is limited edition.

Right.  Things unlimited is just hyperbole.

Could it also be a play on words - in the UK, at least, companies are often named [Something] Limited because they are limited companies?

"limited" could mean "llimited edition", meaning that there are only a small number of them available.

Both uses are advertisements.
"Unlimited" in that sense means that the store or outlet claims that they can supply whatever the customer wants.
The word "limited" in some advertisements means that the product isn't available to just anyone, because of limited production or high price.
